# Long press on up/down scroll button of the slider widget should scroll the slider widget thumb continuously

Tags: eclipse-plugin, swt, eclipse-rcp, draw2d

we have used a Slider widget (org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Slider) in our composite (which is inside a plugin) to scroll the `FigureCanvas` (the canvas's scroll bar has been disabled).

This Slider should function in the same way as the scroll bar. But whenever we long press on the slider widgets buttons they don't get highlighted (as if they are clicked) and the thumb doesn't move continuously. Even if we long press it is considered as 1 click and the thumb moves one increment only.

Do we have to set any values in order to get the expected behavior.

Comment: I figured it out.The dragdetectlsitener is some how blocking the continuous scroll that should happen on long mouse press on the up/down buttons of the Slider. But I dont know why this is happening. Is this an expected behaviour or am I missing something. can there be any workarounds to solve this issue.

Comment: you should post that as an answer and approve it as and correct answer, you can do it, although you answer yourself ;]..

Comment: sorry didn't know that. I am kind of new here. Thank you

Comment: that's ok, welcome here ;], now when you post it like an answer, you can also approve it as correct one, just click on the big check sign under score of your answer..

Comment: i keep getting a box "you can accept your answer in 1 hour" when I click on it.

Comment: That's weird, try it again after some time, and if it will not help post your problem on [meta-stackoverflow](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out.The dragdetectlsitener is some how blocking the continuous scroll that should happen on long mouse press on the up/down buttons of the Slider. But I dont know why this is happening. Is this an expected behaviour or am I missing something. can there be any workarounds to solve this issue?